# Oauth2.0 authentication Google Adsense

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to authenticate using Oauth2. My earlier implementations was using OAuth2Draft10  but since its deprecated now, so I wanted to move to OAuth2.0 http://www.proksi.us/browse.php?u=Oi8vY29kZS5nb29nbGUuY29tL3AvZ29vZ2xlLWFwaS1qYXZhLWNsaWVudC93aWtpL09BdXRoMg%3D%3D&b=143

Mine is an installed application and I am following http://www.proksi.us/browse.php?u=Oi8vY29kZS5nb29nbGUuY29tL3AvZ29vZ2xlLWFwaS1qYXZhLWNsaWVudC93aWtpL09BdXRoMg%3D%3D&b=143#Installed_Applications

but facing problem while calling the authorize() method here, could not get through VerificationCodeReceiver.

Any Help or any guide from where I can get through where I am wrong or missing..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved ..:)

No need to VerificationCodeReceiver.

```
 public static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
        // load client secrets
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(
            JSON_FACTORY, AdSenseSample.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"));


        // set up file credential store
        File jsonFile = new File("/adsense.json"); 

        FileCredentialStore credentialStore = new FileCredentialStore(jsonFile, JSON_FACTORY);

        // set up authorization code flow
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
            Collections.singleton(AdSenseScopes.ADSENSE_READONLY)).setCredentialStore(
            credentialStore).build();
        // authorize
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
      }
```

Thanks..:)

Comment: Where did you get adsense.json file ?

Comment: the adsense.json is where we are persisting the access token and refresh token.